# Are there any cons to putting revision number on app home page?

Tags: web-applications, versioning

There are obvious pros of having revision number somewhere on the page (like on stackoverflow.com): easy for users to identify and report version, when they have issues; easy  way to see that deployment was successful; etc.

Are there any cons to that practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running an Open Source/Packaged Web Application then it may be inadvisable to display the Revision Number because if any Security Holes are found then it is easy to determine if your site is exploitable.

However if you are deploying an internal tool or something then it could be useful like you say for bug reporting and debugging.